# Select to recycle worker processes after a specific period of inactivity

Tags: iis-6, application-pool

Can anyone confirm that this statement "**Select to recycle worker processes after a specific period of inactivity**" in [this Microsoft help file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753667.aspx) is wrong and should in fact not have the "of inactivity" at the end of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that seems wrong. As far as I'm aware, this option just recycles the processes regardless of whether they are idle or not.

[This article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/989a6b5c-289c-4a7c-95b5-175ee4c27159.mspx?mfr=true) seems to confirm that too.

Answer (score -1):

The statement you quoted is correct. It's a way to allow you to free up resources that aren't being used.

> When it is necessary to conserve
>   system resources by terminating unused
>   worker processes, you can configure a
>   worker process to gracefully close
>   after a specified period of time. You
>   can use this feature to better manage
>   the resources when the processing load
>   is heavy, when identified applications
>   consistently fall into an idle state,
>   or when new processing space is not
>   available. You can also start
>   additional worker processes to replace
>   a worker process that is finished.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83b35271-c93c-49f4-b923-7fdca6fae1cf.mspx?mfr=true